# Color discrimination of matrix connected components

Tags: matlab, matrix, colors

In Matlab, I have a matrix M, say:

```
M=[0 0 2 2 0 0
   0 0 2 2 0 3
   1 1 2 2 3 3
   1 1 0 0 0 0
   1 1 0 0 0 0];
```

with some connected components labeled 1,2 and 3.
I need to discriminate the components (1, 2 and 3) by using different colors (red, green and blue for example). Any help to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you please a picture of what you're getting, and what you want it to be?

Comment: If the matrix elements labeled 1,2,3 represent a collection of pixels, how can i color in red the collection 1, in green the collection 2 and in blue the collection 3? (see graph connected components topic)

Comment: So, `image(M+1), colormap([1 1 1; 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1])`?

Comment: @Luis Mendo. Thank you Luis. It works fine!

Comment: Glad it worked. Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`image`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) and [`colormap`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).  From the documentation of the former,

> `image(C)` displays the data in array `C` as an image. Each element of `C`
>       specifies the color for 1 pixel of the image.
>
> When `C` is a 2-dimensional m-by-n matrix, the elements of `C` are used as
>       indices into the current `colormap` to determine the color. For `'direct'` `CDataMapping` (the default),
>       values in `C` are treated as colormap indices (1-based if `double`, 0-based
>       if `uint8` or `uint16`).

Thererfore, you only need to call `image(M+1)`, so that the values start at `1`; and then define a suitable colormap. The colormap is a 3-column matrix, where each row defines a color in terms of its *R*, *G*, *B* components.

```
M = [0 0 2 2 0 0;0 0 2 2 0 3;1 1 2 2 3 3;1 1 0 0 0 0;1 1 0 0 0 0];
imagesc(M+1)       % add 1 so that values start at 1, not 0
cmap = [1 1 1;     % white
        .7 0 0;    % dark red
        0 .7 0;    % dark green
        0 0 .7];   % dark blue
colormap(cmap)     % set colormap
axis tight         % avoid white space around the values
axis equal         % aspect ratio 1:1
```

[image]